# Why does General Grievous' face mask have 3 audio holes at the beginning of the clone wars, then at the end of the clone wars have 4?

Tags: star-wars

From the first picture wee see grievous with 3 voice receptors (whatever the proper terminology is) and then towards the end of the clone wars, grievous seems to have developed a 4th one? as seen in the last two pictures.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I like how you fixate on his speaker grills, and yet all three of those images just begs for a full "spot the differences" list... :)  The "ears" change, the whole mouth area changes, the neck fundamentally changes, the collar changes, the eyes change etc etc  Looks like he has a full on make over at some point.

Comment: The first one seems like the "The clone wars" animated series, the second one seems like some kind of game and the third one is from the movie. I doubt these three were made by the same people. There is a lot of stuff in the animated series that doesn't fit in with the movies, and most SW games are just cash cows. I think the differences come from improper research before getting to work.

Comment: Yes, a common question. The second picture is General Grievous' long lost cousin Colonel Saddus. He came back to aid Grievous because he felt like now that he has four grill holes, he no longer has to feel inferior. The last one, of course, is Saddus' gf, Depressa.

Comment: Actually the 2nd one is from Star Wars the clone wars the lost episodes- featured in the crystal crisis saga

Answer (score 4):

While there is no specific mention of an alteration to his "head" mentioned, [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Grievous) does mention at least two times  when Grievous underwent alterations.

The first was during the episode of *The Clone Wars*, [The Lair Of Grievous](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lair_of_Grievous).

> After Kit Fisto severs Grievous' legs,

Grievous undergoes massive repairs. While the repairs were not specific to his head, it is possible that some additional upgrades may have occurred during that time.

The second instance was during the video game [The Clone Wars: Republic Heroes](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars:_Republic_Heroes), where Grievous uses some of his own parts to repair a droid. It is possible that after using his own parts, he chose to replace them at a later time, and possibly using that moment to upgrade/swap out other portions of himself.

These two instances, of course, are unlikely to be the only times that he modified or upgraded himself. He is, after all, a rage-filled Jedi hunter. He would likely often be attempting to maximize his Jedi-Murdering capabilities.

Comment: And this new speaker grill is JUST the thing to shout at those pesky Jedi right before they die!